# How to display Foreign Key related models fields values in HTML with Django?

Tags: python, html, django, python-3.x

I passed a list from Views.py to HTML in a dictionary value. I loop through the fields. There's one column which is Foreign key to another model. Only that model realted information is not displaying in HTML. How to solve this? The following is the code. The Foreign key column "Course" is not showing but others.
[Screenshot attached here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X1kR2.png)

## Views.py

```
def Student_Main(request):
    objs= Students.objects.values().all()
    template_name = 'genius/students.html'
    context = {'head_title': 'Little Genius Students', 'students':objs}
    return render(request, template_name, context)
```

## HTML

```
<table class="table table-hover">
                <thead class="thead-dark">
                    <tr>
                    <th scope="col">#</th>
                    <th scope="col">Name</th>
                    <th scope="col">DOB</th>
                    <th scope="col">Age</th>
                    <th scope="col">Gender</th>
                    <th scope="col">Grade</th>
                    <th scope="col">School</th>
                    <th scope="col">Course</th>
                    <th scope="col">Address</th>

                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    {% for i in students %}
                    <tr>
                    <th scope="row">{{i.id}}</th>
                    <td><a href=''>{{i.name}}</a></td>
                    <td>{{i.dob}}</td>
                    <td>{{i.age}}</td>
                    <td>{{i.gender}}</td>
                    <td>{{i.grade}}</td>
                    <td>{{i.attending_school}}</td>
                    <td>{{i.course.class_name}}</td>
                    <td>{{i.address}}</td>
                    </tr>
                    {% endfor %}
                </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Please do *not* use [**`.values()`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#values), it should be used very scarcely, for example if you want to make a `GROUP BY` on a set of values. Just omitting the `.values()` will return you `Model` objects, that make use of lazy loading to follow `ForeignKey`s:

```
def Student_Main(request):
    # no .values()
    objs = Students.objects.all()
    template_name = 'genius/students.html'
    context = {'head_title': 'Little Genius Students', 'students':objs}
    return render(request, template_name, context)
```

You can make use of [**`.select_related(..)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#select-related) to prevent the *N+1* problem, and select the related course in the query:

```
def Student_Main(request):
    objs = Students.objects.select_related('course')
    template_name = 'genius/students.html'
    context = {'head_title': 'Little Genius Students', 'students':objs}
    return render(request, template_name, context)
```